# can I use Entity Framework in Asp.Net Pages (Razor)?

Tags: entity-framework, razor

I wonder if I can create Asp.Net Web Pages applications by using Entity Framework. I have not seen an example of this. I wonder why there is no interest in this, or why we are not allowed to do this. Can anyone one help me understand it ?

Comment: I guess the first question will be, "why bother?". MVC/Razor does all that and much more besides. Maybe time to move onwards to the joys of Razor? :)

Comment: Wait, what?  EF is data access/ORM, and Razor is Web/UI.  What does one have to do with the other, and why would you not be "allowed" to use both?